# Abstract user django migration error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-authentication

I am trying to add two fields to user model of Django. Migrations and models are:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_prostudent = models.BooleanField( default=False )
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField( default=False)
```

My migration looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.5 on 2018-02-11 11:07
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import django.contrib.auth.models
import django.contrib.auth.validators
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0008_alter_user_username_max_length'),
        ('students', '0005_auto_20180118_1508'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
                ('username', models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=150, unique=True, validators=[django.contrib.auth.validators.UnicodeUsernameValidator()], verbose_name='username')),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, verbose_name='first name')),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, verbose_name='last name')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=254, verbose_name='email address')),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.', verbose_name='staff status')),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.', verbose_name='active')),
                ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='date joined')),
                ('is_prostudent', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('is_teacher', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
                ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'user',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'users',
                'abstract': False,
            },
            managers=[
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

I have added

```
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'students.User'
```

in my settings.py.

But when I tried to migrate it is showing me the error of lazy reference. 
The field MODEL.User was declared with a lazy reference to students:user, but app 'students' doesn't provide user model.

This thing is occuring because I am doing this in middle of project. Is there any way to do it now. What options do I left with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this major problem of django. Django suggest to update user model in very first of migration. So it is difficult to work on it in mid project.
But there is one way out there for this.

***First clear all the migrations lying in your user model containing app. After this delete your database completely. You can save your database data with the help of fixtures. Fixtures saves your data in JSON format. After that use abstract custom base user. After it have a Happy Migrating.***